# Manipulating a legacy MDB (Access 2.0) with Java 8

Tags: java, ms-access, java-8, jdbc-odbc

The JDBC-ODBC bridge is no longer supported with Java 8. Is there a way to access legacy MDB files without the bridge in Java 8? By legacy, I mean Access 2.0. Such old version is not supported by [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're using the database for - but limited use might open up more options.

1. Try mounting your database with Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable. Probably needs exclusive access to the database.
2. Can you export the database to a flat file or import it into another JDBC-enabled database format? Either Access or another database format? Would require copying the database - probably only work for reporting or read-only access.
3. Set up a sync process to mirror the database into something modern. Some in-memory Java type options: H2/Derby/SQLite. You may need to change your table structure to include last modified dates and manage those.
4. Migrate the Access 2 database to SQL Server or another modern, multi-user database.

Including this info here, in case you are able to get to some intermediate version of Access. What **won't** work as-is:

- [jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) & [stelsMDB](http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb_jdbc.htm) support Access 2000+
- [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) supports Access 95+

Comment: thanks for the helpful info (hence my upvote ;). But I need to read and modify these old MDB files in-place. It's pretty stupid, I know... but some very old Brazilian government systems use these Access 2.0 MDBs and there's no way around it.

Comment: Jackcess did allow me to at least read some of these old files, which solved part of my problem. Cheers!

Comment: Great! I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sun's and Oracle's [official positions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) have long been that --

> the [JVM-bundled] JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution [...] Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.

However, my employer, [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has produced enterprise-grade commercial Type 1 Bridges between JDBC and ODBC since Java 1.0, and these are fully compatible with the current Java 8 and any ODBC standard-compliant driver, including Microsoft's ODBC driver for Access.  You can learn more here --

- [Single-Tier JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/) -- a JDBC driver for ODBC data sources
- [Single-Tier ODBC-JDBC Bridge Driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/) -- an ODBC driver for JDBC data sources